# How do I use a js function to insert text at location the function is called?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to write something like the following html and js code in which I can call the Walking function many times in the text of the html, and for the function to make a calculation and place the result in place of the script tags.

But I cannot find an appropriate js function to write the html in the correct place without having to define for example a span element with a given ID that I would have to pass through to the function each time.

```js
function Walking(distance, ascent, descent) {
  // Calculate walking time from distance, ascent and descent 
  // and display this and other info at point the function is called.
}
```

```html
Walk for
<script>
  Walking(1000, 100, 0);
</script> until you arrive at ... Then walk steeply uphill for
<script>
  Walking(2500, 1100, 0);
</script> to reach the summit.
```

Comment: Look for the nearest element with a given class? There’s lots of ways this could be implemented—the “best” depends on how the elements are being added and their structure.

Comment: Have a look at document.write(). However, that is not a robust or modern way of doing things.

Comment: @DeeGee Very bad idea.

Comment: Scripts are executes one by one when the page is loading. So yes you need other markers  like spans or divs to write in

Comment: @mplungian I agree! but it's what he is asking, it's valid, and self-taught first steps are a voyage of discovery...?

Comment: @DeeGee They did not ask how to do it poorly ;)

Comment: Generally you don't embed javascript in the middle of content. Instead, you'd use an element with needed data associated with it, then have an isolated script that finds and updates those elements based on their data.

Comment: Will you have to replace the results after they have initially replaced their script tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not trivial, but you can learn a lot from the code below.

Components:

- [Event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)
- [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [ternary/conditional operaot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const avgWalk = 4; // km/h
const ascWalk = 2;
const dscWalk = 4.5;
const decimalHoursToHHMM = num => { 
  let n = new Date(0,0); 
  n.setSeconds(+num * 60 * 60); // convert to seconds
  let [HH,MM] =  n.toTimeString().slice(0, 5).split(":"); // convert to HH:MM and spread the result to HH and MM
  return +HH === 0 ? `${+MM}m` : `${+HH}h${+MM}m`; // using template literals
};
// Calculate walking time from distance, ascent and descent 
// and display this and other info at point the function is called.

const Walking = ([distance, ascent, descent]) => decimalHoursToHHMM(
    (distance/1000)/avgWalk - 
    (ascent/1000)/ascWalk + 
    (descent/1000)/dscWalk);

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when page has loaded
  document.querySelectorAll(".calc")  // all elements with class "calc"
   .forEach(span => span.textContent = Walking(JSON.parse(span.dataset.parms))); // use the data-parms for values and set the textContent
})
```

```html
Walk for <span class="calc" data-parms="[1000, 100, 0]"></span> until you arrive at ... Then walk steeply uphill for
<span class="calc" data-parms="[2500, 1100, 0]"></span> to reach the summit.
Return trip should last <span class="calc" data-parms="[5000, 0, 5000]"></span>.
```

Comment: Or just fill some container from script at once.

Comment: @JanPfeifer I chose to make it simple to write the text regardless of the complexity of the code.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, a far more comprehensive answer than I was expecting. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) and [`replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith), to replace the function-calling script element (e.g. with text):

```html
<script>
function addText() {
  document.currentScript.replaceWith(" and added text");
}
</script>

Default text<script>addText();</script>.
```

Note that the function needs to be defined earlier than where the call happens.

Comment: That is nasty and only works once

Comment: @mplungjan I would consider this neither a good nor a bad practice. This is an _analogous alternative_ to server-rendering, which is what was asked for: To "place the result in place of the script tags".

Comment: Operative word: Tags. Yours only works once per tag

Comment: Thank @OskarGrosser, I appreciate your time in answering.